# DateDiff not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, automationstudio

I am using the datediff function and it doesn't seem to be working.

What I am currently using

```
DATEDIFF(year, creation_date__c, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()) AS AnniversaryYears
```

It just gives an empty result in the data extension for AnniversaryYears.

creation_date__c is of the following format: Monday, December 05, 2016 12:00 AM

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: in your DE, is  creation_date__c a Date field or a text field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your field `creation_date__c` is of the correct type, date, this should fulfil your use case:

```
SELECT
DATEDIFF(year, creation_date__c, getdate()) AS AnniversaryYears
FROM
DataExtensionName
```

Result:

[image]

The difference between GETDATE() and SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() is that the latter will just add the time zone, which won't be comparable to `creation_date__c` since it doesn't have a timezone.

Comment: It is of the datetime type, so your solution is also not working :/

Comment: sure, but what do you see in the Data Extension properties for that field? Does it say `Date` or `Text` or something else?

Comment: Date, like you show in the screenshot. My bad.

Comment: @user3485470 Can you post your full query into your question, it may be a syntax issue outside of this snippet that is causing the issue.

Comment: I was mapping it to the wrong attribute. I had AS AnniversaryYears while the attribute was called YearsAnniversary. Ima cry myself to sleep. Thanks anyways! Would have expected an error message for that invalid mapping though.

Answer (score 4):

The issue might be that the date format of the two is not matching correctly.

Try using:

 `DATEDIFF(year, CAST(creation_date__c as DATE), CAST(getdate() as DATE))`

So that you cast each as identical data types, which should remove any possible data mismatch.